# Issue with date_default_timezone_set()?

Tags: php, timezone

Please tell me how to use `date_default_timezone_set()` for Ottawa. Currently I am using `date_default_timezone_set("Canada/Newfoundland")`. But I want this for Ottawa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the PHP documentation for a [list of supported time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).  You will find these are standard [IANA TZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) identifiers, as also [listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Ottawa should be covered by `America/Toronto`.